# Spring boot Keep getting "required a single bean, but 10 were found" although I declared only one service

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, xml-configuration

Whenever I run my spring boot application I keeb getting the following message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field patchService in org.hisp.dhis.dxf2.metadata.objectbundle.DefaultObjectBundleService required a single bean, but 10 were found:
    - org.hisp.dhis.patch.DefaultPatchService#0: defined in URL [file:/D:/001Learning/JavaEE/Projects_FromNet/eagleboard2/eagleboard-services/eagleboard-service-core/target/classes/META-INF/dhis/beans.xml]
    - org.hisp.dhis.patch.DefaultPatchService#1: defined in URL [file:/D:/001Learning/JavaEE/Projects_FromNet/eagleboard2/eagleboard-services/eagleboard-service-core/target/classes/META-INF/dhis/beans.xml]
    - org.hisp.dhis.patch.DefaultPatchService#2: defined in URL [file:/D:/001Learning/JavaEE/Projects_FromNet/eagleboard2/eagleboard-services/eagleboard-service-core/target/classes/META-INF/dhis/beans.xml]
    - org.hisp.dhis.patch.DefaultPatchService#3: defined in URL [file:/D:/001Learning/JavaEE/Projects_FromNet/eagleboard2/eagleboard-services/eagleboard-service-core/target/classes/META-INF/dhis/beans.xml]
    - org.hisp.dhis.patch.DefaultPatchService#4: defined in URL [file:/D:/001Learning/JavaEE/Projects_FromNet/eagleboard2/eagleboard-services/eagleboard-service-core/target/classes/META-INF/dhis/beans.xml]
    - org.hisp.dhis.patch.DefaultPatchService#5: defined in URL [file:/D:/001Learning/JavaEE/Projects_FromNet/eagleboard2/eagleboard-services/eagleboard-service-core/target/classes/META-INF/dhis/beans.xml]
    - org.hisp.dhis.patch.DefaultPatchService#6: defined in URL [file:/D:/001Learning/JavaEE/Projects_FromNet/eagleboard2/eagleboard-services/eagleboard-service-core/target/classes/META-INF/dhis/beans.xml]
    - org.hisp.dhis.patch.DefaultPatchService#7: defined in URL [file:/D:/001Learning/JavaEE/Projects_FromNet/eagleboard2/eagleboard-services/eagleboard-service-core/target/classes/META-INF/dhis/beans.xml]
    - org.hisp.dhis.patch.DefaultPatchService#8: defined in URL [file:/D:/001Learning/JavaEE/Projects_FromNet/eagleboard2/eagleboard-services/eagleboard-service-core/target/classes/META-INF/dhis/beans.xml]
    - org.hisp.dhis.patch.DefaultPatchService#9: defined in URL [file:/D:/001Learning/JavaEE/Projects_FromNet/eagleboard2/eagleboard-services/eagleboard-service-core/target/classes/META-INF/dhis/beans.xml]

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Although Only one Service is declared in the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd">

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.preheat.PreheatService" class="org.eagleboard.preheat.DefaultPreheatService" scope="prototype">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.calendar.CalendarService" class="org.eagleboard.calendar.DefaultCalendarService" />

  <bean class="org.eagleboard.calendar.impl.Iso8601Calendar" />

  <bean class="org.eagleboard.calendar.impl.CopticCalendar" />

  <bean class="org.eagleboard.calendar.impl.EthiopianCalendar" />

  <bean class="org.eagleboard.calendar.impl.GregorianCalendar" />

  <bean class="org.eagleboard.calendar.impl.IslamicCalendar" />

  <bean class="org.eagleboard.calendar.impl.NepaliCalendar" />

  <bean class="org.eagleboard.calendar.impl.ThaiCalendar" />

  <bean class="org.eagleboard.calendar.impl.PersianCalendar" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.query.planner.QueryPlanner" class="org.eagleboard.query.planner.DefaultQueryPlanner" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.query.QueryParser" class="org.eagleboard.query.DefaultQueryParser" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.query.CriteriaQueryEngine" class="org.eagleboard.query.CriteriaQueryEngine" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.query.InMemoryQueryEngine" class="org.eagleboard.query.InMemoryQueryEngine" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.query.QueryService" class="org.eagleboard.query.DefaultQueryService" />

  <bean class="org.eagleboard.patch.DefaultPatchService" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.render.RenderService" class="org.eagleboard.render.DefaultRenderService" />

  <bean class="org.eagleboard.amqp.RabbitMQAmqpService" />


  <bean id="org.eagleboard.interpretation.InterpretationStore" class="org.eagleboard.interpretation.hibernate.HibernateInterpretationStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.interpretation.Interpretation" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <!--Eagle Board part-->

  <!-- Eagle Board Data Stores -->
  <bean id="com.eagleboard.datafield.DataFieldStore" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.datafield.hibernate.HibernateDataFieldStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.datafield.DataField" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="com.eagleboard.fieldset.FieldSetStore" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.fieldset.hibernate.HibernateFieldSetStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.fieldset.FieldSet" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="com.eagleboard.todotask.TodoTaskStore" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.todotask.hibernate.HibernateTodoTaskStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.todotask.TodoTask" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="com.eagleboard.activity.ActivityStore" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.activity.hibernate.HibernateActivityStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.activity.Activity" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="com.eagleboard.project.ProjectStore" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.project.hibernate.HibernateProjectStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.project.Project" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Eagle Board Services -->
  <bean id="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.datafield.DataFieldService" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.datafield.DefaultDataFieldService">
    <property name="dataFieldStore" ref="com.eagleboard.datafield.DataFieldStore" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.fieldset.DefaultFieldSetService" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.fieldset.DefaultFieldSetService">
    <property name="fieldSetStore" ref="com.eagleboard.fieldset.FieldSetStore" />
    <property name="currentUserService" ref="org.eagleboard.user.CurrentUserService" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.todotask.DefaultTodoTaskService" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.todotask.DefaultTodoTaskService">
    <property name="todoTaskStore" ref="com.eagleboard.todotask.TodoTaskStore" />
    <property name="currentUserService" ref="org.eagleboard.user.CurrentUserService" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.activity.DefaultActivityService" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.activity.DefaultActivityService">
    <property name="activityStore" ref="com.eagleboard.activity.ActivityStore" />
    <property name="currentUserService" ref="org.eagleboard.user.CurrentUserService" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.project.DefaultProjectService" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.project.DefaultProjectService">
    <property name="projectStore" ref="com.eagleboard.project.ProjectStore" />
    <property name="currentUserService" ref="org.eagleboard.user.CurrentUserService" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Eagle Board DeletionHandlers -->
  <bean id="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.datafield.DataFieldDeletionHandler" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.datafield.DataFieldDeletionHandler">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.fieldset.FieldSetDeletionHandler" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.fieldset.FieldSetDeletionHandler">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.todotask.TodoTaskDeletionHandler" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.todotask.TodoTaskDeletionHandler">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.activity.ActivityDeletionHandler" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.activity.ActivityDeletionHandler">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.project.ProjectDeletionHandler" class="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.project.ProjectDeletionHandler">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorStore" class="org.eagleboard.indicator.hibernate.HibernateIndicatorStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.indicator.Indicator" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorTypeStore" class="org.eagleboard.common.hibernate.HibernateIdentifiableObjectStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorType" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorGroupStore" class="org.eagleboard.common.hibernate.HibernateIdentifiableObjectStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorGroup" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorGroupSetStore" class="org.eagleboard.common.hibernate.HibernateIdentifiableObjectStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorGroupSet" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.period.PeriodStore" class="org.eagleboard.period.hibernate.HibernatePeriodStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.period.Period" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
    <property name="transientIdentifiableProperties" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.expression.ExpressionStore" class="org.eagleboard.hibernate.HibernateGenericStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.expression.Expression" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.UserStore" class="org.eagleboard.user.hibernate.HibernateUserStore">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.user.User" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.CurrentUserStore" class="org.eagleboard.user.hibernate.HibernateCurrentUserStore" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.UserSettingStore" class="org.eagleboard.user.hibernate.HibernateUserSettingStore">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.UserAuthorityGroupStore" class="org.eagleboard.user.hibernate.HibernateUserAuthorityGroupStore">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.user.UserAuthorityGroup" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.UserCredentialsStore" class="org.eagleboard.user.hibernate.HibernateUserCredentialsStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.user.UserCredentials" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.UserGroupStore" class="org.eagleboard.common.hibernate.HibernateIdentifiableObjectStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.user.UserGroup" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.UserGroupAccessStore" class="org.eagleboard.hibernate.HibernateGenericStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.user.UserGroupAccess" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.UserAccessStore" class="org.eagleboard.hibernate.HibernateGenericStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.user.UserAccess" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.PasswordValidationService" class="org.eagleboard.user.DefaultPasswordValidationService" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.PasswordHistoryValidationRule" class="org.eagleboard.user.PasswordHistoryValidationRule" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.PasswordLengthValidationRule" class="org.eagleboard.user.PasswordLengthValidationRule" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.DigitPatternValidationRule" class="org.eagleboard.user.DigitPatternValidationRule" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.UpperCasePatternValidationRule" class="org.eagleboard.user.UpperCasePatternValidationRule" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.SpecialCharacterValidationRule" class="org.eagleboard.user.SpecialCharacterValidationRule" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.PasswordDictionaryValidationRule" class="org.eagleboard.user.PasswordDictionaryValidationRule" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.UserParameterValidationRule" class="org.eagleboard.user.UserParameterValidationRule" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.message.MessageConversationStore" class="org.eagleboard.message.hibernate.HibernateMessageConversationStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.message.MessageConversation" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="statementBuilder" ref="statementBuilder" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.configuration.ConfigurationStore" class="org.eagleboard.hibernate.HibernateGenericStore">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.configuration.Configuration" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.constant.ConstantStore" class="org.eagleboard.common.hibernate.HibernateIdentifiableObjectStore">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.constant.Constant" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.scheduling.JobConfigurationStore" class="org.eagleboard.common.hibernate.HibernateIdentifiableObjectStore">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.scheduling.JobConfiguration" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.deletedobject.DeletedObjectStore" class="org.eagleboard.deletedobject.hibernate.HibernateDeletedObjectStore" />

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.version.VersionStore" class="org.eagleboard.version.hibernate.HibernateVersionStore">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.version.Version" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.metadata.version.MetadataVersionStore"
    class="org.eagleboard.metadata.version.hibernate.HibernateMetadataVersionStore">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.metadata.version.MetadataVersion" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.option.OptionSetStore" class="org.eagleboard.common.hibernate.HibernateIdentifiableObjectStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.option.OptionSet" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.option.OptionStore" class="org.eagleboard.option.hibernate.HibernateOptionStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.option.Option" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.option.OptionGroupStore" class="org.eagleboard.option.hibernate.HibernateOptionGroupStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.option.OptionGroup" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.option.OptionGroupSetStore" class="org.eagleboard.option.hibernate.HibernateOptionGroupSetStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.option.OptionGroupSet" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.legend.LegendSetStore"
    class="org.eagleboard.common.hibernate.HibernateIdentifiableObjectStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.legend.LegendSet" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
  </bean>


  <bean id="org.eagleboard.i18n.I18nLocaleStore" class="org.eagleboard.i18n.hibernate.HibernateI18nLocaleStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.i18n.locale.I18nLocale" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.keyjsonvalue.KeyJsonValueStore" class="org.eagleboard.keyjsonvalue.hibernate.HibernateKeyJsonValueStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.keyjsonvalue.KeyJsonValue" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.userkeyjsonvalue.UserKeyJsonValueStore"
    class="org.eagleboard.userkeyjsonvalue.hibernate.HibernateUserKeyJsonValueStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.userkeyjsonvalue.UserKeyJsonValue" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.fileresource.FileResourceStore" class="org.eagleboard.common.hibernate.HibernateIdentifiableObjectStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.fileresource.FileResource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.fileresource.ExternalFileResourceStore"
    class="org.eagleboard.fileresource.hibernate.HibernateExternalFileResourceStore">
    <property name="clazz" value="org.eagleboard.fileresource.ExternalFileResource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.fileresource.FileResourceContentStore" class="org.eagleboard.fileresource.JCloudsFileResourceContentStore">
    <property name="configurationProvider" ref="dhisConfigurationProvider" />
    <property name="locationManager" ref="locationManager" />
  </bean>
  <!-- File resource jobs -->

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.fileresource.FileResourceUploadCallback" class="org.eagleboard.fileresource.FileResourceUploadCallback" />

  <!--<bean id="fileResourceCleanUpJob" class="org.eagleboard.fileresource.FileResourceCleanUpJob" />-->

  <!-- Service definitions -->

  <!--<bean id="org.eagleboard.dataelement.DataElementGroupService" class="org.eagleboard.dataelement.DefaultDataElementGroupService" />-->

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorGroupService" class="org.eagleboard.indicator.DefaultIndicatorGroupService">
    <property name="indicatorGroupStore" ref="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorGroupStore" />
  </bean>

  <!--<bean id="org.eagleboard.dimension.DimensionService" class="org.eagleboard.dimension.DefaultDimensionService" />-->

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.fileresource.FileResourceService" class="org.eagleboard.fileresource.DefaultFileResourceService">
    <property name="fileResourceStore" ref="org.eagleboard.fileresource.FileResourceStore" />
    <property name="fileResourceContentStore" ref="org.eagleboard.fileresource.FileResourceContentStore" />
    <property name="schedulingManager" ref="org.eagleboard.scheduling.SchedulingManager" />
    <property name="uploadCallback" ref="org.eagleboard.fileresource.FileResourceUploadCallback" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.fileresource.ExternalFileResourceService" class="org.eagleboard.fileresource.DefaultExternalFileResourceService">
    <property name="externalFileResourceStore" ref="org.eagleboard.fileresource.ExternalFileResourceStore" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorService" class="org.eagleboard.indicator.DefaultIndicatorService">
    <property name="indicatorStore" ref="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorStore" />
    <property name="indicatorTypeStore" ref="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorTypeStore" />
    <property name="indicatorGroupStore" ref="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorGroupStore" />
    <property name="indicatorGroupSetStore" ref="org.eagleboard.indicator.IndicatorGroupSetStore" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.period.PeriodService" class="org.eagleboard.period.DefaultPeriodService">
    <property name="periodStore" ref="org.eagleboard.period.PeriodStore" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.expression.ExpressionService" class="org.eagleboard.expression.DefaultExpressionService">
    <property name="expressionStore" ref="org.eagleboard.expression.ExpressionStore" />
    <property name="dataFieldService" ref="org.eagleboard.eagleboard.datafield.DataFieldService" />
    <property name="constantService" ref="org.eagleboard.constant.ConstantService" />
    <property name="idObjectManager" ref="org.eagleboard.common.IdentifiableObjectManager" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="org.eagleboard.user.UserSettingService" class="org.eagleboard.user.DefaultUserSettingService">
    <property name="currentUserService" ref="org.eagleboard.user.CurrentUserService" />
    <property name="userSettingStore" ref="org.eagleboard.user.UserSettingStore" />
    <property name="userService" ref="org.eagleboard.user.UserService" />
    <property name="systemSettingManager" ref="org.eagleboard.setting.SystemSettingManager" />
  </bean>
```

`PatchService` interface:

```
public interface PatchService
{
    Patch diff( PatchParams params );
    void apply( Patch patch, Object target );
}
```

`DefaultPatchService.java` implementing that interface

```
public class  DefaultPatchService implements PatchService
{
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog( DefaultPatchService.class );

    private final SchemaService schemaService;

    private final QueryService queryService;

    private final AmqpService amqpService;

    private final MetadataAuditService metadataAuditService;

    private final CurrentUserService currentUserService;

    private final RenderService renderService;

    private final SystemService systemService;

    public DefaultPatchService( SchemaService schemaService, QueryService queryService, AmqpService amqpService,
        MetadataAuditService metadataAuditService, CurrentUserService currentUserService, RenderService renderService, SystemService systemService )
    {
        this.schemaService = schemaService;
        this.queryService = queryService;
        this.amqpService = amqpService;
        this.metadataAuditService = metadataAuditService;
        this.currentUserService = currentUserService;
        this.renderService = renderService;
        this.systemService = systemService;
    }
...
```

`DefaultObjectBundleService.java` in which the `DefaultPatchService` is `Autowired` using the interface it implements `PatchService` which implemented only by it, no other service implementing this interface.

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class DefaultObjectBundleService implements ObjectBundleService
    {
        private static final LoggingManager.Logger log = LoggingManager
            .createLogger( DefaultObjectBundleService.class );

        @Autowired
        private CurrentUserService currentUserService;

        @Autowired
        private PreheatService preheatService;

        @Autowired
        private SchemaService schemaService;

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Autowired
        private IdentifiableObjectManager manager;

        @Autowired
        private DbmsManager dbmsManager;

        @Autowired
        private HibernateCacheManager cacheManager;

        @Autowired
        private Notifier notifier;

        @Autowired
        private MergeService mergeService;

        @Autowired
        private DeletedObjectService deletedObjectService;

        @Autowired
        private PatchService patchService;

        @Autowired
        private MetadataAuditService metadataAuditService;

        @Autowired
        private RenderService renderService;

        @Autowired
        private SystemService systemService;

        @Autowired
        private AmqpService amqpService;

        @Autowired( required = false )
        private List<ObjectBundleHook> objectBundleHooks = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public ObjectBundle create( ObjectBundleParams params )
        {
            PreheatParams preheatParams = params.getPreheatParams();

            if ( params.getUser() == null )
            {
                params.setUser( currentUserService.getCurrentUser() );
            }

            preheatParams.setUser( params.getUser() );
            preheatParams.setObjects( params.getObjects() );

            ObjectBundle bundle = new ObjectBundle( params, preheatService.preheat( preheatParams ), params.getObjects() );
            bundle.setObjectBundleStatus( ObjectBundleStatus.CREATED );
            bundle.setObjectReferences( preheatService.collectObjectReferences( params.getObjects() ) );

            return bundle;
        }
...
...
```

could someone help me, please, also the project have multiple modules, Does dependency between modules have something to do with the problem

Comment: `<bean class="org.eagleboard.patch.DefaultPatchService" />` appears twice in your beans.xml snippet.

Comment: I searched for multiple `DefaultPatchService` in the xml file and found only one occurrence of it.

Comment: Could you post the whole beans.xml, at least in the snippet you posted there are two occurrences  one in the first line the other on line 5.

Comment: I added the whole beans.xml, there was an error in the question and i fixed it by pasting from the source code, the file is big and I posted two-third of it.

Comment: Turn your logger to DEBUG into spring configuration. I'm betting that the error is not related with the DefaultPatchService but with the DefaultCalendarService which you have 9 different impl files for it (and I would say +1 for the default one)...

Comment: OR you may have non XML configuration into your codebase.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I will look again for any occurrence of non-XML configuration, although I already looked multiple times, anyway, is it possible that a certain interleaving of dependency between modules can cause that?, I mean I want to be assured that the problem is only a configuration problem so I take my time finding it in this part of the problem.

Comment: It really depends on your codebase. And yes, if the modules are being loaded and they are using the same interfaces that's definitely possible.

Comment: I will look into all your suggestions and let you know, meanwhile, if someone has any other suggestions I would be thankful, Thank you all

Comment: When I comment out the part that instantiates the services in the XML file: <bean class="org.eagleboard.patch.DefaultPatchService" /> and try to run the app I get the error that I should consider defining a bean of type 'org.eagleboard.patch.PatchService' in my configuration, which means it is not defined anywhere else other than that one definition, Where the problem would be? It's driving me crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the service xml definition from this:

```
<bean class="org.eagleboard.patch.DefaultPatchService" />
```

to this:

```
<bean id="org.eagleboard.patch.PatchService" class="org.eagleboard.patch.DefaultPatchService" />
```

and the error stopped showing up.
many thanks for all.